# NoUislider change opacity on block element

Tags: javascript, opacity, nouislider

I want to change the opacity of a div or image by using noUiSlider, but it won't display the block. What am I missing?

```js
var opacitySlider = document.getElementById("slider");

        noUiSlider.create(opacitySlider, {
            behaviour: 'drag', 
            start: 0,
            range: {
                min: 0,
                max: 1
                }
            });  
            
        var o = opacitySlider.noUiSlider.get();
            
        var changeOp =
            document.getElementById("block").style.opacity = o ;
```

Any help or advice would be great. [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/martinkean/enwvkmkk/10/#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your opacity assignment into the update method:

```
opacitySlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ){
    document.getElementById("block").style.opacity = values[handle] ;
    directionField.innerHTML = values[handle];
});
```

You were calling it just once, on page load.

Comment: That's great! Thanks Serg!